# How to make _users/_all_docs accessible for regular users?

Tags: couchdb

Is it possible to make `_users/_all_docs` accessible for regular logged users?

In couchdb config I added already under [couch_httpd_auth] the param-value pairs `users_db_public = true` and `public_fields = name`. But this does only work for user specific read-requests like:

```
GET http://localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:testuser
```

So how can a regular user fetch all other users with only their public fields?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Somehow I didn't need it anymore. So sadly no :/ But maybe it is possible by defining a custom view and calling the custom view instead.

Answer (score 0):

Same question.. may be replicate local _users db to other db and get all_docs

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.